# JDK 7 dmg "No mountable file system"

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to update the JDK for Eclipse on my MAC, but I keep getting this "no mountable file system" every time I try to open the dmg. Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: run    md5 "downloaded filename" and compare the output to that linked from the download page

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the file is corrupted.
Redownload the file again.
if that doesn't work, try to remove the old jdk and install the new one.

Comment: The problem turned out to be my MAC. My version on my OS couldn't support JDK7.